# Как сделать вращение, чтобы оси не вращались вместе с объектом?

Tags: c#, opengl

Я изучаю OpenGL (а именно `TAO fraemwork`) на C#, и у меня возник такой вопрос:

Есть, допустим куб, и я хочу его вращать всегда по одной и той же системе координат, как это правильно реализовать? Функции по типу `glRotate()` или вращение путем умножения матриц непосредственно вращает ось координат объекта (куба), и после вращения, скажем, по оси Y, оси X и Z для объекта уже не будут прежними.

Так как же реализовывать вращение, чтобы оси не вращались вместе с объектом? Приветствуются как прямые ответы, так и косвенные: ссылки на книги или туториалы где можно откопать инфу, но такие чтобы там можно было найти ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Советую вам прочитать про [кватернионы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), точнее про то, как их используют в компьютерной графике и робототехнике.

Если очень кратко, то это альтернативный обычному(углы Эйлера) вариант вращения, основанный на оси и угле (axis-angle rotation).

Как и матрицы они могут аккумулировать вращения, то есть вы можете составлять из них цепочки, без опаски получить блокировку оси (gimbal lock) как бывает в случае с углами Эйлера. И в то-же время, в отличие от матриц, они могут хорошо интерполироваться из одного положения в другое.

Это может показаться очень сложным однако, для того чтобы пользоваться свойствами, понимать внутреннюю кухню кватернионов не обязательно.

UPD: [вот](https://habrahabr.ru/post/255005/) неплохая статья

Comment: Добрый день!
Благодарю Вас за Ваш ответ, @Stranger in the Q.
В поисках ответа в гуглах я натыкался на то что стоит использовать кватернионы в данное проблеме, и даже по некоторым туториалам сварганил класс кватерниона. Код по ссылке: https://github.com/Despairon/SimpleRubicsCube/blob/24dcddd9c3fe9f97157ef0c820578888162e4bca/SimpleRubicsCube/Quaternion.cs
Но результатом его использования является все то же вращение, подобное `glRotate()`

Comment: вот интересная статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/255005/

Comment: Вы не могли бы подсказать по поводу той статьи которую Вы кинули?
Там написано следующее: "Рисунки, изображающие поворот и подписанные как «global» демонстрируют повороты относительно неподвижных осей XYZ. Такой результат мы получим, если будем использовать кватернионы разворота по отдельности." Это вот именно то, что мне нужно. Кватернион, как я понял, содержит в себе коорды вектора - оси Но что значит использовать кватернионы по отдельности, это как? 
Спасибо

Comment: имеется ввиду что для вычисления суперпозиции при сумме нескольких вращений кватернионы просто перемножают

Comment: Но ведь перемножение кватернионов дает результат - вращение относительно локальной системы координат объекта, там так и написано. А мне нужно вращение относительно глобальной

Answer (score 0):

> Так как же реализовывать вращение, чтобы оси не вращались вместе с объектом?

Непонятно чего хочется сделать, при вращении (да и вобще при любом аффинном преобразовании) вы переходите из одной системы координат в другую, например повернув куб относительно своего центра вокруг оси X локальная система координат куба также будет повёрнута, важно понимать что любое преобразование выполняется относительно какой - то выбранной системы координат, в вашем случае относительно мировой.

Пусть `Rx(alpha), Ry(betta), Rz(gamma)` будут матриами поворота вокруг соответсвующих осей на углы `alpha, betta, gamma`.

А `T(v)` матрицей переноса, где `v` это позиционный вектор переноса.

Тогда координаты вершин куба повёрнутого относительно вектора `v` вокруг выбранных осей будут вычисляться по формуле

`transformedVector = T(v)*Rz(gamma)*Ry(betta)*Rx(alpha)*T(-v)`

или если используя старые `openGL` функции то так:

```
glPushMatrix(); // сохраняем в стек текущую модельную матрицу чтобы последующие пребразования затронули только куб
   glTranslatef(x, y, z);
   glRotate(alpha, ...);
   glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
glPopMatrix()`
```

в обоих случаях мы переходим в начало координат, поворачиваем, и возвращаемся обратно на своё место.

А блокировка осей это другой вопрос, и он в случае с Эйлеровским вращением естественно может возникнуть.

Но для того чтобы использовать кватернионы необходимо разобраться сперва в преобразованиях вообще.

Comment: Короче без картинок не обойтись)
Смотрите: комментатор @StrangerInTheQ посоветовал статью: https://habrahabr.ru/post/255005/. В конце статьи есть подписанные картинки: вращение самолета подписанное global и вращение подписанное local. Если последовательно в openGL выполнить два `glRotate(...)`, то вращаться объект будет ровно так как показано на картинках с подписью local. А я хочу вращать так как на картинках с подписью global, и я понятия не имею как это сделать, как только я не пробовал. Спасибо!